# SQL Status of Parent with Parent-Child relationship in other table

Tags: sql

In table 1 I have records with a status.

| key | Status | Combi | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | ABCD | 1 | 0 |
| key2 | ABCD | 1 | 0 |
| key3 | XYZ | 1 | 0 |
| key4 | XYZ | 1 | 1 |
| key5 | QWERT | 1 | 1 |
| key6 | ABCD | 0 | 0 |

In table 2 I have the parent child relationship

| key | Parentkey | Check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | key4 | A |
| key2 | key4 | B |
| key3 | key5 | A |
| key4 | key4 | B |
| key5 | key5 | A |

The Result I'm looking for is a table with the ParentStatus. But only when Table1.Combi = 1 and Table1.Parent = 0 and Table2.Check = A. Like this:

| key | ParentStatus |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | XYZ |
| key2 |  |
| key3 | QWERT |
| key4 |  |
| key5 |  |
| key6 |  |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the conditions such as `check_ = 'A'` in the join condition.  If we use where then the lines will not be returned.

> ```
> create table table1 (key_ varchar(10), status varchar(10), combi int, parent int);
> insert into table1 values
> ('key1','ABCD',1,0),
> ('key2','ABCD',1,0),
> ('key3','XYZ',1,0),
> ('key4','XYZ',1,1),
> ('key5','QWERT',1,1),
> ('key6','ABCD',0,0);
>
> create table table2(key_ varchar(10), ParentKey varchar(10), Check_ char);
> insert into table2 values
> ('key1','key4','A'),
> ('key2','key4','B'),
> ('key3','key5','A'),
> ('key4','key4','B'),
> ('key5','key5','A');
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   t.key_,
>   ttt.status Parent_Status
> from table1 t 
> left join table2 tt 
> on t.key_ = tt.Key_ and Check_ = 'A' and parent = 0
> left join table1 ttt
> on tt.ParentKey = ttt.key_ and t.combi = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> key_ | parent_status
> :--- | :------------
> key1 | XYZ          
> key2 | null         
> key3 | QWERT        
> key4 | null         
> key5 | null         
> key6 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2bc7b4936bb85c832a1110611d347234)*